# Replace the <img /> tag from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How could I replace or remove all the image tag in my string using javascript?

```html
Coffee Bean<div><br /></div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gxYSUNDX.." />
```

I want to remove the image and the successive image tag in a string. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/402322)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
myString.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
```

[^>]* means any number of characters other than >. If you use .+ instead, if there are multiple tags the replace operation removes them all at once, including any content between them. Operations are greedy by default, meaning they use the largest possible valid match.

/g at the end means replace all occurrences (by default, it only removes the first occurrence).

Comment: so u mean it is better to use the + operation for removing any count of img tag in a string?

Comment: The + means "one or more" in regex, so it will remove all counts.
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: I've tried that solution but it doesn't work to my code.

Comment: it's okay already, I've got my mistake, it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, upvote and mark the answer if it was helpful. Thanks !